# how to concatenate two values in Scala using foreach method

Tags: scala

I have the following two values that I want to concatenate:

```
val x: Range = (1 to 20)

val y: List[List[Double]] = List(List(4.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99), List(4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 0.0, 0.0))
```

Desired output:

Table 1 order is (4.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99)

Table 2 order is (4.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99)

Getting:

```
Table 1List(4.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99)
Table 1List(4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 0.0, 0.0)
Table 2List(4.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99)
Table 2List(4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 0.0, 0.0)
```

I used foreach and println to get the above:

```
x.foreach(i=>{
  y.foreach(j=>{
  println("Table " + i +" order is " + j)
  })})
```

So I have two questions:

1. how to stop the repetition
2. how to remove the List from the output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't want to iterate over a cartesian product of `y` and `1 to 20`. Use `zipWithIndex` instead. To get rid of `List(...)` in the output, use `mkString`.

```
for ((list, tableIdx) <- y.zipWithIndex) {
  println(s"Table ${tableIdx + 1} order is ${list.mkString("(", ", ", ")")}")
}
```

Comment: Thanks@Andrey.Can you explain how this  "(", ", ", ")" argument works for mkString method please.

Comment: @mike, if you don't have access to the Scala API doc, you're in for a painful time. If you do, then look it up there https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SeqLike.html#mkString(start:String,sep:String,end:String):String

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the value x to accomplish what you want: Your code can be modified as follows to to get your wanted output with no repetitions:

```
   y.zipWithIndex.foreach(j=>{
     println("Table " + (j._2+1) +" order is " + j.toString.drop(5).dropRight(3))
    })
```

The specific answers to your questions are:

1. If you remove the x value from your code, there will be no repetitions.
2. By using `j.toString.drop(5).dropRight(3)` you will not get the `List(` (5 chars) and the tailing additional 3 chars due to `zipWithIndex` operation.

### In Scala REPL:

```
scala> y.zipWithIndex.foreach(j=>{
        println("Table " + (j._2+1) +" order is " + j.toString.drop(5).dropRight(3))
      })
Table 1 order is (4.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99)
Table 2 order is (4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 0.0, 0.0)
```